# Google Service Account linked to Analytics Account, are there any limitations as to how many?

Tags: api, google-analytics, service-accounts, developer-console

We've been using a google service account linked to our clients Analytics API to retrieve data used in reporting. This has been working great until late when our clients started getting "Google-Internal Error, Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)" errors when trying to add the user to their analytics account.

[image: error message in analytics when trying to add the service account]

Checking the quota we're not even close to exhausting it. I'm not aware of any limitations regarding how many analytics accounts a service account can be linked to so I'm not really sure whats causing this error. Anyone else had this problem or can assist in resolving the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not able to find any source to this fact, it does seem like there is a limitation with regard to how many analytics account a service account can be linked to. The solution we chose was to create an additional service account which we had our new clients add to their analytics account:

[image]